# command line cURL works but php one doesnt

Tags: php, curl, authentication

The code:

```
// That works pretty well
curl -d "user%5Blogin%5D=some%40email.pl&user%5Bpass%5D=testpass&user%5Bmemory%5D=on&user%5Bsubmit%5D=Login" -L -c cookie.txt http://turbobit.net/user/login


//But this PHP code doesn't

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Referer' => 'http://turbobit.net/');
    $postdata = array('user%5Blogin%5D' => 'some%40email.pl', 'user%5Bpass%5D' => 'test', "user%5Bsubmit%5D" => 'Login', 'user%5Bmemory%5D' => 'on');
    $cookie = "/srv/http/test/regexturbobit/cookie.txt";

    $c = curl_init('http://tutbobit.net/user/login');
    curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    $output=curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    print_r($output);
```

it just doesn't show anything and even dont save cookie...

Comment: did you spell the domain name wrong? that domain doesn't exist

Comment: I suspect it's all example data, given `some@email.pl`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$postdata = 'user%5Blogin%5D=some%40email.pl&user%5Bpass%5D=testpass&user%5Bmemory%5D=on&user%5Bsubmit%5D=Login';
```

You shouldn't have URLencoded keys in a postdata array as they'll be URL-encoded again. Alternatively you could do:

```
$postdata = array(
  'user[login]' => 'some@email.pl',
  'user[pass]' =>  'test',
  // the rest of the vars here...
);
```

But note that **passing an array for `$postdata` will not send a URL-encoded request**, it will send a request with `multipart/form-data` encoding. From the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To
> post a file, prepend a filename with @
> and use the full path. This can either
> be passed as a urlencoded string like
> 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an
> array with the field name as key and
> field data as value. If value is an
> array, the Content-Type header will be
> set to multipart/form-data.

So, if you pass an array, the values and keys should not already be URLEncoded.

Comment: The section piece in this answer is wrong, as it this code also sends the wrong kind of POST.

Comment: @Daniel: I provided code for both kinds of POST. The first example is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the second is `multipart/form-data`. I also included an excerpt form the manual explaining why the second was `multipart/form-data`. And, if he's POSTing to a PHP script, most likely either method will work.

Comment: Not at all, very few server-side scripts accept either POST approach. They almost always are written to accept only one of them.

Comment: Your statement just disregarded nearly the entire PHP scripting language. Surely you realize that a significant number of server side scripts are written in PHP? A majority of the time, PHP doesn't care if the postdata is url or multipart encoded. The values will be in `$_POST` either way.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide the data as a hash array, the POST will not be a "normal" POST anymore but it will instead make a multipart formpost.

Multipart formposts ([RFC1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)) are very different than the normal -d one your command line uses.

A nice trick is to use append "--libcurl example.c" to your curl command line to get to see the C source code for what could be used to run the same operation.

Comment: While you're correct that `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` are two very different ways of encoding postdata, "the POST will not be a 'normal' POST" isn't exactly correct. It's still an HTTP POST operation, and most likely the webserver will accept either kind. The URL provided in the question works just fine with `multipart/form-data` posts.

Comment: well your response didn't even attempt to explain the differences so thus it was not at all clear that you understood or even considered them. I think that misleads anyone who reads the question and the answers, hence my clarifications.

Comment: I agree my response could make that more clear. I will edit it now.

Comment: I see you're the maintainer of the `libcurl` package which means your C-skills and your knowledge of RFCs far exceed mine... I think we agree on the fundamental concepts here and are just arguing over semantics, which is not something I want to do... and certainly not with someone who maintains what I consider to be one of the most useful libraries I've ever used. I use libcurl in my code all the time! `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: http://github.com/shuber/curl